# How to fix the issue with very small screen size with Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

We just ran into a problem in our test automation infrastructure. The problem is that Windows defaults to a very small screen size (I assume 800x600) while running from [Jenkins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_(software)). Then if the website under test doesn't support such a small resolution without overlapping UI elements, the browser will fail some tests for items that are no longer visible. How can we solve this?

Comment: `driver.manage().window().maximize();` or `driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920,1080));` ?

Answer (score 4):

It would be best maximize your window as soon as you instantiate your web driver instance.

I don't know the setup of your code but please try adding the following line after you've created an instance of the web driver you wish to use:

### Java

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

### C#

```
_driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
```

### Python

```
driver.maximize_window()
```

### Ruby

```
@driver.manage.window.maximize
```

The above may not work in Chrome - if this is the case, please use:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArgument("--start-maximized");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

As per @Ardesco & @Fenio comments - you can also set a specific dimension using:

```
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920,1080));
```

Comment: Maximising will not help if the native resolution of the machine running the tests is 800 * 600.  It would be better to set a specific dimension as per @Fenio's comment

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.manage().window().fullscreen()
```

Comment: please ass context around your answer. (From Review).

Comment: @ZF007 please dont use vulgar language

Comment: @markroxor .. well spotted... should be "add".. but you knew, didn't you ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Within your driver setup you can change the browser window size using the following in `C#`

```c#
driver.Manage().Window.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(width: 1600, height: 1200);
```